# Closure Compiler does not always enforce type safety?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I'm having an issue with closure compiler where it's not enforcing strict type checks for some strange reason.  It correctly checks type safety when setting a variable where it's declared, but is failing to throw an type error when passing an object.

```
/**
 *  @public
 *  @param x {number}
 */
SomeClass.prototype.setterMethod = function(x) {

    this.var1 = x;

};

var a = new SomeClass();
a.setterMethod({}); // SHOULD THROW AN ERROR!!!!!!
```

Why isn't closure compiler enforcing type safety here?  It correctly functions if I declare the variable:

```
this.var1 = {};  // correctly throws an error
```

However it is not enforcing strict type safety checks on function parameters, or when setting the class member variable outside of the member declaration.  I've posted the full code and output below.  Is there a way to force closure to force these types of checks?  Or am I doing something wrong here?

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @warning_level VERBOSE
// @output_file_name default.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/**
 *  @class SomeClass
 *  @constructor
 */
function SomeClass() {

    /**
     *  @protected
     *  @type {number}
     */
    this.var1;

};

/**
 *  @public
 *  @param x {number}
 */
SomeClass.prototype.setterMethod = function(x) {
    this.var1 = x;
};

/**
 *  @public
 *  @returns {number}
 */
SomeClass.prototype.getterMethod = function() {
    return this.var1;
};

/**
 *  @type {SomeClass}
 */
var a = new SomeClass();
a.setterMethod({});
console.log(a.getterMethod());

// output: -- NO WARNINGS!!!!
// var a=new function(){};a.a={};console.log(a.a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues occurring:

1. The Closure-compiler web service runs in a type of "demo" mode and assumes all undeclared variables are external. There is currently no way to disable this. Testing with the command line compiler doesn't show the same issues.
2. Your JSDoc paramater annotation is not correct. It should be `@param {number} x` (you have the type and name reversed).

Comment: yep, reversing the declaration fixes the issue. Otherwise the "type" is simply seen as a comment for the param :  @param {number} x

Comment: Thanks guys.  Much appreciated.  Funny because the compiler throws warnings that x doesn't exist if you name it incorrectly, but also in the incorrect spot.  I'll log a bug.